# ESRI JS API - Buffer FeatureLayer

Tags: javascript, geometry, buffer, arcgis-js-api

I have a Feature Layer that I would like to buffer using user input and a geometry service.

FeatureLayer:

```
    var texasPipeline = new FeatureLayer(pipeURL, {
        mode: FeatureLayer.MODE_ONDEMAND,
        outFields: ["*"],
        definitionExpression:texasPipeQuery
    });
```

BufferParameters:

```
        var params = new BufferParameters();
        params.distances = [distance];
        params.unit = units;
        params.outSpatialReference = map.spatialReference;
        params.geometries = texasPipeline;
        map.graphics.clear();
        geomSvc.buffer(params, showBuffer);
```

The server is returning an error saying that geometries must be supplied. My guess here is that i need to pass in the geometry of the FeatureLayer as opposed to the FeatureLayer itself. How do i get at the geometries of the FeatureLayer and appropriately pass that into the BufferParameters??

EDIT:
Additionally I have tried to loop through as you can see in the code bellow. passing the array of geometries into the BufferParameters still does not return successfully.

```
        var texasPipelineGeom = [];
        var graphics = texasPipeline.graphics;
        for (var G in graphics) {
            var g = graphics[G]["geometry"];
            console.log(g);
            texasPipelineGeom.push(g);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

What is the error you re receiving with the edits you made, that looks to be a good start. The buffer parameters does take an array of geometries instead of a feature layer.

You could use something like this (untested, just take as pseudo code):

```
params.geometries = texasPipeline.graphics.map(function (graphic) {
  return graphic.geometry;
});
```

If using polygons, sometimes the geometry service will complain about the polygons not being simplified.  You can find a full working example with polygons here: https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/jssamples/util_buffergraphic.html, You will just need to correctly get your geometries out of the feature layer and add them to `params.geometries`.

```
var buffer = function buffer (point, radius) {
  var promise = new Deferred();
  var gsvc = new GeometryService(CONFIG.GEOMETRY_SERVICE_URL);
  var params = new BufferParameters();
  params.geometries = [point];
  params.distances = [radius];
  params.unit = GeometryService.UNIT_KILOMETER;
  params.outSpatialReference = new SpatialReference(54010);

  gsvc.buffer(params, promise.resolve, console.error);

  return promise;
};
```

Comment: Gotta love Esri's helpful error messages :(. I added an example that works for me, try to match that the best you can, if you do and stlil see a 400 error, it may be that there is an issue with the geometry in your feature layer, try sending it in with a simple point instead or simplifying it first with geometry services simplify method.  In this function, I pass in a ArcGIS Point and 50 as my radius.

Answer (score 0):

What vesrion of js api you are using? Starting from version 3.13 there is a module [esri/geometry/geometryEngine](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/jsapi/esri.geometry.geometryengine-amd.html). With this module you can do geometry operation on the client side without geometry service. [Here](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/jssamples/ge_geodesic_buffers.html) is a good example of using it.

---

Also take a look at module [esri/graphicsUtils](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/jsapi/esri.graphicsutils-amd.html) to get geometries from graphics.